# Powershell diff xml and grab Xpath

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath, web-config

I am trying to diff two xml files, (IIS web.config) and I need to grab the Xpath where the change happens.

so lets say in file A I have:

```
 <configuration>
   <system.serviceModel>
     <services>
        <service name="some service">
          <endpoint address= "abc">
        </service>
     </services>
   </system.serviceModel>
 </configuration>
```

and in file B I have

```
<configuration>
   <system.serviceModel>
     <services>
        <service name="some other service">
          <endpoint address= "xyz">
        </service>
     </services>
   </system.serviceModel>
 </configuration>
```

I am using the command

```
Compare-Object (Get-Content FileA)(Get-Content FileB)
```

this gives me the output

```
<endpoint address= "abc">        =>
<endpoint address= "xyz">        <=
```

There are files with multiple **endpoints** so I need to differentiate between them based on their absolute Xpath so I can query it back and replace those values with the correct ones.

Any Ideas??!!

Comment: Those aren't valid XML files (the <endpoint> element isn't closed. Is your real data valid xml?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the Xpath, or would the actual nodes do? I think the easiest thing is to use the differing values themselves to lookup the node (though that may not work well if there are duplicates):

```
[xml] $a = Get-Content \temp\a.xml
[xml] $b = Get-Content \temp\b.xml

Compare-Object ($a.SelectNodes("//endpoint").address) ($b.SelectNodes("//endpoint").address) |
ForEach-Object {$i = $_.InputObject; switch($_.SideIndicator) {
  "=>" { $xpath = "//endpoint[@address='$i']"; @{xpath_b=$xpath; node=$b.SelectNodes($xpath)} }
  "<=" { $xpath = "//endpoint[@address='$i']"; @{xpath_a=$xpath; node=$a.SelectNodes($xpath)} }
}}
```

With this sample input (a.xml):

```
<configuration>
   <system.serviceModel>
     <services>
        <service name="some service">
          <endpoint address= "abc" />
          <endpoint address= "def" />
        </service>
     </services>
   </system.serviceModel>
 </configuration>
```

and (b.xml):

```
<configuration>
   <system.serviceModel>
     <services>
        <service name="some service">
          <endpoint address= "abc" />
          <endpoint address= "xyz" />
        </service>
     </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

You would get this output:

```
Name    Value                     
----    -----                     
xpath_b //endpoint[@address='xyz']
node    {endpoint}                
xpath_a //endpoint[@address='def']
node    {endpoint}
```

In practice though you could just manipulate the nodes directly in the switch statement rather than outputting those values.